# debug ajax php with netbeans xdebug

Tags: ajax, netbeans, xdebug

I have jquery making an ajax call to another php file and cannot workout how to get netbeans and xdebug to stop at a breakpoint on this file.
EG:

index.php

```
function ajaxfunc(){
    ...
}
```

other.php

```
<?php
    echo Whatever::doit();
    class Whatever(){
            public function doit(){
                $stopme="now";
            }
    }
?>
```

Netbeans stops at code in index.php but not in other.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug to your ajax url.

that will turn on debugging for your ajax call. make sure the project you have open has the other.php file in it.